# where does the actual parameter go in the closure function?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am doing my 1.1 learning ( means very basic ) on Javascript, now i am stuck in the chapter of "the closure function", here are my codes..

```js
function a() {
  let n = 0;

  function b(m) {
    n = m + n;
    return n
  }
  return b
}

let c = a();
console.log(c(3)); // result: 3
console.log(c(3)); // result: 6
console.log(c(3)); // result: 9
console.log(c(3)); // result: 12
```

so, I know when i give an actual parameter 3 to c, that at same time means give the actual parameter 3 to function a, like a(3), but how it goes automatically to add itself to formal parameter of function b to add itself again and again and end up being 6,9,12......etc. ?
in other word, I didn't set any formal parameter in function a to catch the given actual parameter, how did all these happen ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: At the moment `c` is not a function (so your code will throw an error). Did you mean to `return b` in your example?

Comment: hey, sorry I did a typo, in the end of function a, it should be return b, NOT return b(),

Comment: since "c is not a function " was said, but how did c(3) works, i was taught that everytime you want to use a function just put () after, (roughly), 

Comment: `let c = a()` here `a()` returns function `b()` which has closure to `n`,  now when you do `c(3)` you're actually passing value to `b(3)` and inside `b` you're doing `n = m + n` so it increases value of `n` by passed parameter everytime you call it

Comment: @CodeManiac  I got it ! thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

> I know when i give an actual parameter 3 to c, that at same time means
> give the actual parameter 3 to function a, like a(3)

This is not the case, when you give the actual parameter `3` to `c`, it becomes the formal parameter of the function `b`. Here's why:

When you `return b`, you're returning a function, which is yet to be called. So, you can visualize the line `let c = a()` as so:

```
let c = function b(m) {
  n = m + 0; // m + n becomes n + 0, because `n` is set to `0` initially in `a`
  return n
}
```

So, when you later call `c(3)`, you're actually calling the function returned by `a` (ie: function `b`). This means, `3` becomes the formal parameter of `b`, which is then used as the value of `m` in your function.

And so, each time you perform an increment on `n` (by doing `n = m + n`), your value for `n` the next time you call `c` will be the sum of previous values passed through into `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let c = a()
```

here `a()` returns `function b()` which has closure to `n`, now when you do `c(3)` you're actually passing value to `b(3)` and inside `b` you're doing `n = m + n` so it increases value of `n` by `passed parameter` to `c()` every time you call it

---

Watch out the debugger section of image to see what actually `c` has `clsoures`

[image]

```js
function a() {
  let n = 0;

  function b(m) {
    n = m + n;
    return n
  }
  return b
}

let c = a();

console.log(c(3)); // result: 3
console.log(c(3)); // result: 6
console.log(c(3)); // result: 9
console.log(c(3)); // result: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `c(3)` it basically calls b function with parameter 3. When you are calling `a()` it creates a new instance of the function, and the `n` variable equals 0. Calling `c(3)` will change the value to 3, cause it updates the n value with the calculated expression (`0 + 3`). And so on. Calling another `c(3)`, will update n param of your instance of function with `3 + 3`. I hope it helps u understand it.